# The proper way to use promise.All, and await to loop through a list of file operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Well, I am lost in await and async hell. The code below is supposed to loop through a list of files, check if they exist and return back the ones that do exist. But I am getting a zero length list.

Node V8 code: caller:

```
await this.sourceList()
if (this.paths.length == 0) {
    this.abort = true
    return
}
```

Called Functions: (I took out stuff not relevant)

```
const testPath = util.promisify(fs.access)

class FMEjob {
    constructor(root, inFiles, layerType, ticket) {
        this.paths = []
        this.config = global.app.settings.config
        this.sourcePath = this.config.SourcePath
    }
    async sourceList() {
        return await Promise.all(this.files.map(async (f) => {
            let source = path.join(this.sourcePath, f.path)
            return async () => {
               if (await checkFile(source)) {
                   this.paths.push(source)
               }
            }
        }))
    }
    async checkFile(path) {
        let result = true
        try {
            await testPath(path, fs.constants.R_OK)
        }
        catch (err) {
            this.errors++
            result = false
            logger.addLog('info', 'FMEjob.checkFile(): File Missing Error: %s', err.path)
        }
        return result
    }
```

Comment: why are you putting awaits everywhere? have `sourceList` return a `Promise.all`, and do await only when calling sourceList

Comment: `return await Promise.all(this.files.map(async (f) => {` - I have no idea what this does, but I think you should split all this into functions, and test that each function, individually works. Although I wouldn't mix Promise.all with async/await. If you want to run multiple calls using await, just use a regular for loop.

Comment: I origially tried a for loop, but even with the await, it was returning immediately. I know that the checkFile works, I use it in another part of the program. My issue here was to try to use it in a for loop. but that did not work, so I went to Promise.all()

Comment: If `await checkFile()` was returning immediately that's probably where your problem is. Maybe try first to get it working in a simple async function.

Comment: @this.lau_ Using `Promise.all` is essential for concurrency

Comment: What irrelevant stuff did you take out concretely? I suspect there's a missing `this.` before the `checkFile` call

Comment: yea, I think my rapid typing and re-typing fixes for the last hour resulted in me losing the this one time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `sourceList` function is really weird. It returns a promise for an array of asynchronous *functions*, but it never calls those. Drop the arrow function wrapper.

Also I recommend to *never* mutate instance properties inside `async` methods, that'll cause insane bugs when multiple methods are executed concurrently.

```
this.paths = await this.sourceList()
if (this.abort = (this.paths.length == 0)) {
    return
}
```

```
async sourceList() {
    let paths = []
    await Promise.all(this.files.map(async (f) => {
        const source = path.join(this.sourcePath, f.path)
        // no function here, no return here!
        if (await this.checkFile(source)) {
            paths.push(source)
        }
    }))
    return paths
}
async checkFile(path) {
    try {
        await testPath(path, fs.constants.R_OK)
        return true
    } catch (err) {
        logger.addLog('info', 'FMEjob.checkFile(): File Missing Error: %s', err.path)
        this.errors++ // questionable as well - better let `sourceList` count these
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: believe me, I really did not want to mutate this.paths. I did it as a last resort since I did not now how to return the list of paths.

Comment: well @Bergi this works fantastic, and I learned some stuff. Do you agree with this.lau_ that this could have been done simpler with a for loop?

Comment: @Dr.YSG No, a for loop would have been *different*, checking the files sequentially.

Comment: That is what I figured also. BTW: any idea how to track these things down? (node:13348) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.